# Need assistance regarding custom UITableView and custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

This is screenshot of whatsapp, I have to create a tableview just like this one.

1. It has space on left side (Dont know top two cell are custom or default with right detail style).
2. Few cells in between have no separators.

How I am suppose to do same with my `uitableview`.

Answer (score -1):

1. Start from iOS 7 [left inset](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/separatorInset) of UITalbeViewCell is default. Default value is 15, but you can change it.
2. This is not a few cells. This is One custom cell. I mean work+main+iPhone it is one cell.

Comment: inset will move the whole cell and images are set without space and Its not one custom cell, I can tap them individually.

Comment: if you can tap it individually then it is custom 1 pixel view on bottom. On some cells it is exists, on other - no.

Comment: @S.J you can inset cells individually, so indent the ones that have no image, but not the ones that do.

Comment: @rdelmar a little code sample will be very useful regarding setting individual cell inset.